# How to delete text from an edited picture in preview?

Tags: photos, preview, image-editing

I recently edited a picture in preview by adding text to it. I then saved it, not realizing that the original would not be saved (without the text). When I went in to the picture later to delete the text, it was not possible. Is there a way I can either recover the original photo or delete the text I already saved?

Comment: File -> Revert To -> Browse All Versions...

Answer (score 2):

There **is** a way to remove text from a picture that you have added with Apple's Preview application.

Open the picture with Preview, try to find as area where the background is the same as where the text is.

- Select an area with the mouse, and copy it and paste it into the picture.
- It will pop up in the center of the picture.
- Use the mouse to move it over the text.
- You can paste it several times as needed.
- Save and quit the application.
- Re-open Preview and Open Previous.

Select the picture you just edited and the text will be gone.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same situation and figured out that you can remove and undo the addition of the text by simply going to drop down under File and selecting "Revert To" and then selecting "Browse All Versions".  There you will be able to select the version without the text.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

That is one Problem with Preview that needs fixing by Apple.

It will unfortunately without warring overwrite your original.

There is no way to restore the original.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Photoshop CS5 or newer, you might try one of the selecting tools to select the text and use Content Aware Fill and/or the Clone Stamp Tool to remove the text. (This does not make your text editable, but the text can still be removed)

One way is to sample the text color with the Eyedropper Tool. Use Select > Color Range. Use Select > Modify > Expand.. (about 2 piksels to cover the antialiasing). Deselect other parts of the image with the same color. Then use Content Aware Fill. Redo Content Aware Fill or use Clone Stamp Tool on problem areas.

Older Photoshop versions and [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/) (free) also have a Clone Stamp Tool (not Content Aware Fill).

Answer (score -1):

Open image in photos, click on image in tool bar, click on show edit tools. Once that opens look for revert to original image and click on that. Close show edit tools and it should revert back to the original photo.  It worked for me to remove text.  Hope this helps.